# Add Custom Header in Http Request using ngx-restangular in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, restangular, angular-http

I am using [ngx-restangular](https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular/) for http requests in Angular 4. I have to set up a custom header at some event taking some input from user and after that the Token is created which is to be passed to the `Requestheader` in the **API**.

Here is the code which I have used for  setting the custom header.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { RestangularModule, Restangular, RestangularHttp } from 'ngx-restangular';
import { RestangularConfigFactory } from '../app.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions,  } from '@angular/http';


@Component({
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    model: any = {};
    loading = false;
    returnUrl: string;
    headers: Headers;
    options: RequestOptions;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private restangular: Restangular) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // reset login status
        // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
        this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    }

    login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(this.model.username + ':' + this.model.password));
        this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
        console.log(this.options);
        this.restangular.one('authentication').one('user').get([''], [this.headers]).subscribe( response => {
            console.log(response);
          });
    }
}
```

now using this I am getting the Output[image: ActualImage]
and I need something like this [image: DesiredImage]

In the **desired image** image below you can see the in the `Request Header` a new field named `authorization` is there which I want to achieve using `ngx-restangular`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Use interceptor =>

```
RestangularProvider.addFullRequestInterceptor((element, operation, path, url, 
headers, params)=> {
   return {
     params: Object.assign({}, params, {sort:"name"}),
     headers: headers,
     element: element
   }
 });
```

https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular#addfullrequestinterceptor

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.